# Create a query (sum from diferent tables)

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have 3 tables and I want to sum the value:

```
Table 1  
id............value  
31001.........200  
31002.........100  
31003.........1  
31004.........0  
31005.........0  


Table 2  
id...........value  
31001.........1  
31002.........1  
31004.........5  

Table 3  
id...........value  
31001.........2  
31003.........2  
31005.........1
```

I have tried using the following code:

```
SELECT table1.id, Sum([table1].[Value]+[table2].[Value]+[table3].[Value])
FROM (table1 LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.[id] = table2.[id]) LEFT JOIN table3 ON table1.[id] = table3.[id]
WHERE (((table2.id) Is not Null) and (table3.id) and (table2.id))
GROUP BY table1.id;

UNION

SELECT table1.id,Sum([table1].[Value]+[table2].[Value])
FROM table1 LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.[id] = table2.[id]
WHERE (((table2.id) Is not Null))
GROUP BY table1.id;

UNION

SELECT table1.id,Sum([table1].[Value]+[table3].[Value])
FROM table1 LEFT JOIN table3 ON table1.[id] = table3.[id]
WHERE (((table3.id) Is not Null))
GROUP BY table1.id;
```

I want a result like:

```
id.........value  
31001.......223  
31002.......111  
31003.........3  
31004.........5  
31005.........1
```

But I'm getting

```
id..........value  
31001.......221  
31001.......222  
31001.......223  
31002.......111  
31003.........3  
31004.........5  
31005.........1
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Do UNION ALL instead of UNION. GROUP BY the UNION ALL result.

Comment: Why `31001.......223`? The sum of 200 + 1 + 2 = 203.

Comment: @forpas ups, typo. The 200 should be 220.

Comment: This makes sense. Did you try my answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First use `UNION ALL` for all 3 tables and then sum over the column `value` by `id`:

```
select id, sum(value) as totalvalue from (
  select id, value from table1
  union all
  select id, value from table2
  union all
  select id, value from table3
)
group by id
order by id
```

The result will be:

```
id  totalvalue
31001   203
31002   101
31003   3
31004   5
31005   1
```